# Changing icon on CMS homepage

Tags: image, cms, magento2.3.4, home-page, icon

I am new to Magento.

I am trying to make changes in CMS homepage.

The page looks like this:

[image]

I am able to change page *title* and *heading* from **cms_page** table.

But not able to find way to change the icon containing *Luma* by replacing it with image I have.

How should I proceed with that?

Comment: do you mean logo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the logo of your Magento store, Please follow the below steps.

Step:1
Log in backend and open content theme configuration.
Content -> Design -> Configuration

[image]

Step:2
Content -> Design -> Configuration->Select theme configuration
Open Design theme configuration and select theme which enabled in your storefront.

[image]

Step:3

Content -> Design -> Configuration->Edit theme configuration->
Edit your theme which is enabled in your storefront and upload new logo which you want as new.

[image]

Step:4
After did all the above steps you need to clean cache via terminal.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Good Luck, Hope this solution useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Content > Configuration > Select your current theme > Header
> ```

[image]